# Make nginx gzip only if asked

Tags: nginx, http-headers, gzip

It seems like once gzip is turned on, it will only gzip even if the request doesnt set Accept-Encoding: gzip in the header.

Is there anyway so that if the request doesnt set Accept-Encoding, it will not return gzip?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is the case, at least with nginx 1.6.2 (the server I tested against).  I only have `gzip on;` and `gzip_types text/html application/javascript text/css application/json;` in my config, and it properly returns "un-compressed" when Accept-Encoding isn't supplied.

Comment: my nginx is 1.4.6 ill try to update first

Comment: yeah i have the same exact config as yours and my nginx is now 1.7... still giving me gzipped payload all the time =(

Comment: Could you post a minimum working config that exhibits that behavior?  And is nginx behind any sort of proxy or load balancer?

Comment: my config:
```gzip on;```
```gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;```
```gzip_disable "msie6"```;

and no load balancer/proxy

Comment: Do you have access to `curl` for testing purposes?

Comment: yes i do have `curl`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74861/discussion-between-lsowen-and-aluksidadi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try viewing the headers with `curl -I http://example.com/` (where example.com is replaced with your site).  Verify that `Content-Encoding: gzip` isn't in the resulting headers.

Often other test clients add headers (including `Accept-Encoding`) automatically, which can make testing problematic.

Side note:  If you are interested in verifying that the server does return gzip encoding when requested, you can use the alternate test query 'curl -I --compressed http://example.com/`.

Comment: you are right. it doesnt gzipped the payload. i was using postman chrome extension to test. i guess since its web browser based, it will auto ask for gzip. Thanks!!